# Combining two consecutive density plots

Tags: plotting, legending

I would like to combine two density plots using Show[ ] with different consecutive x-values so that the color scheme and legends match. For example,

```
plot01 = DensityPlot[2 Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> "M10DefaultDensityGradient", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]

plot02 = DensityPlot[2 Sin[x y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> "M10DefaultDensityGradient", 
PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

As such, plot01 has a scheme based on the range {0.0, 2.0} while plot02 has one based on the range {-2.0, 2.0}. I would like both of them to have a color scheme and legend based on {-2.0, 2.0} so that when they are combined, the colors match smoothly. How do I make this happen?

Comment: If you use single `DensityPlot` for full range `{x, 0, 3}` you will get what you want automatically. Why are you plotting the same function in different plots and then trying to stitch them?

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use `Show` with two separate plots (rather than a single one with `{x, 0, 3}`), you can specify the range for color scheme as `{-2,2}` in both plots and add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
plot01 = DensityPlot[2 Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 3}, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {-2, 2}}], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
plot02 = DensityPlot[2 Sin[x y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[ {"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {-2, 2}}], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False];
Legended[Show[plot01, plot02, PlotRange -> All], 
 BarLegend[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {-2, 2}}]]
```

[image]